# check validation of logical expression in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a string contains a valid expression or not in javascript, regex will also work

Input valid string - ((c1 and c2) or c3) and c4
Input invalie string - (c1 and c2) or) c4 and

Comment: You have to *define* what you consider a valid expression before you can encode a validator for it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide necessary details. Note, SO is for problems and not for requirements.

Comment: this is valid expression with balance parenthesis((c1 and c2 or c2) and c4) on the other hand  invalid expression is (c1andc2 or c3 ))

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda a fun way:

If You have a string like:

```
var str = 'true && true'
```

you can create a function out of it:

```
var fn = new Function('return ' + str);
fn(); // returns true
```

Anything that would be invalid would fail when creating the function.